# Websphere MQ and mule avoid message loss

Tags: java, jms, mule, messaging, ibm-mq

I am using Websphere MQ and using Mule connectors to consume messages from a Queue.WE have implemented rollback exception strategy block in Mule to redeliver the messages in case of any JMSException.

```
<rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="3" when="exception.causeMatches('javax.jms.')" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" />
```

So the strategy tries to redilver 3 times before consuming the messages. This results in a message loss. I want the message to be rollbacked to the Websphere MQ and to be redilevered after a certain delay.Do we have such configuration available for Websphere MQ Connectors(Active MQ has it) ? Basically I wish to avoid message loss. Are there any other approaches which I should check?

Please suggest the best design to avoid Message Loss?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working only with WMQ, you can use a local transaction for this:

```
<wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="SOME.IMPORTANT.QUEUE">
    <wmq:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
</wmq:inbound-endpoint>
```

If you are working with some other transport, you can look into multi transactions or XA:

```
<wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="SOME.IMPORTANT.QUEUE">
    <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
</wmq:inbound-endpoint>
```

Be sure to update any outbound endpoints that should participate in the transaction so that they use action="ALWAYS_JOIN" as well.

More info [on the Mule User Guide](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management).